# Why adding noise into image data failed CNN regression learning

Tags: deep-learning, convolution, training-data, loss

I am running an object localization task with CNN regression. I got pretty good results with the original data.

However, after I added 5% noise into the original data in the augmentation process, the loss values during the training looks ok, but the validation fluctuates a lot during the training. And when I check the results after the training was done, the neural nets always predicted a constant output. That is, the output from the networks never changes regardless of the input data, which means the neural network was trapped into a dead valley. How could this happen since I added variability into the data, and how to avoid that?

The code to add noise:

```
    sindex = 0;
    for n in range(n_train):
        cndata = normalized_data[n, :, :, :]
        #        plt.matshow(np.squeeze(prepped_data[sindex, :, :,:]))
        # add noise, augmentation, and shift in x and y
        for x in range(1):
            noise = np.random.normal(0, noise_sd, (xres, xres, slices))
            ishift = np.random.randint(low=1, high=(row - xres), size=2)
            prepped_data[sindex, :, :, :, 0] = cndata[ishift[0]:ishift[0] + xres, ishift[1]:ishift[1] + xres, :] + noise
            prepped_label[sindex, :] = labelData[:, n] + [-ishift[0], -ishift[1], 0, -ishift[0], -ishift[1], 0, 0]
            sindex = sindex + 1

Loss function definition:
    model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=['accuracy', root_mean_squared_error])

RMSE definition:
    def root_mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred):
        return K.sqrt(K.mean(K.square(y_pred - y_true), axis=-1))
```

Here is the original training curve without noise:
[image]

Here is the training curve after adding noise:
[image]

Comment: provide the code where you add noise, calculate loss, optimize. It's hard to spot an error without seeing the code

Comment: Here is the code for adding noise:

Comment: sindex = 0;
    for n in range(n_train):
        cndata = normalized_data[n, :, :, :]
        for x in range(1):
            noise = np.random.normal(0, noise_sd, (xres, xres, slices))
            ishift = [int((row - xres) / 2), int((row - xres) / 2)]
            prepped_data[sindex, :, :, :, 0] = cndata[ishift[0]:ishift[0] + xres, ishift[1]:ishift[1] + xres, :] + noise
            prepped_label[sindex, :] = labelData[:, n] + [-ishift[0], -ishift[1], 0, -ishift[0], -ishift[1], 0, 0]
            sindex = sindex + 1

Comment: loss:
    model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=['accuracy', root_mean_squared_error])

    def root_mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred):
        return K.sqrt(K.mean(K.square(y_pred - y_true), axis=-1))

Comment: sorry for the mess. do not know how to correct the format. looked ok while I was writing the comment.

Comment: You better make it as question update (edit). What is your noise_sd value?

Comment: the noise_sd is 0.05*(maximum pixel value in the image volume)

Comment: I did not see a place to edit my question. Where is it?